# Strange overlapping rendering in THREE.js (and some shadow issues)

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is my second foray into the world of THREE.js, the first being a short one. I just set up this scene to try some things out. It's a flat box mesh with three box meshes sitting on it. For some reason, the boxes on top are being rendered behind certain polygons of the ground mesh. Anyone have any idea why this is? Does it have something to do with the scale of the scene, or some setting I'm missing? Thanks.

While I have you, does anyone know why the meshes aren't casting directional light shadows onto the ground mesh?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k8E43/1/

```
var scene, camera, renderer;
var material;
var player, ground, mesh1, mesh2;
var directionalLight, spotLight, ambientLight;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 450;
    camera.position.z = 750;
    camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 150, 0 ) );

    material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );

    // Meshes

    player = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 70, 160, 70 ), material );
    player.position.y = 80;
    player.castShadow = true;
    player.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( player );

    ground = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1000, 10, 600 ), material );
    ground.position.y = -5;
    ground.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( ground );

    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 40, 100 ), material );
    mesh1.position.x = -150;
    mesh1.position.y = 20;
    mesh1.position.z = 100;
    mesh1.castShadow = true;
    mesh1.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( mesh1 );

    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 200, 100 ), material );
    mesh2.position.x = 150;
    mesh2.position.y = 100;
    mesh2.position.z = -100;
    mesh2.castShadow = true;
    mesh2.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( mesh2 );

    // Lights

    directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
    directionalLight.position.x = -1000;
    directionalLight.position.y = 500;
    directionalLight.position.z = -1000;
    directionalLight.target.position.x = 1000;
    directionalLight.target.position.y = -500;
    directionalLight.target.position.z = 1000;
    directionalLight.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 );
    scene.add( ambientLight );

    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}
var lightIncreasing = false;
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

Comment: I added segments to the cubes (more than 1) and it seemed to help a bit. Is this the solution or is there another answer? Shadows still aren't being cast.

Comment: Use the WebGLRenderer instead of the CanvasRenderer

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Thanks a lot. That worked.